# Calculo de data com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

tenho um script que precisa fazer a diferença dentre 2 datas coletas de alguns arquivos

No caso o script coleta a data de um arquivo .txt (dt_log) e a data atual do systema (dt_sys) e minha dificuldade é achar a diferença entre essas 2 datas

Exemplo

O arquivo foi criado no dia 20/07/2018 10:05:55
A data do sistema é 25/07/2018 11:10:02

O retorno que eu precisaria que fosse impresso é de 120 horas (5 dias = 120 horas)

É possível fazer isso?

Segue trecho do código:

```
# LOG DATE AND SYSTEM DATE
## LOG dt_log = os.stat(log[0]) dt_log = time.ctime(dt_log.st_ctime) dt_log = dt_log.split(' ') print("Hora da Log: ", dt_log[3])

## SYSTEM dt_sys = time.time() dt_sys = time.ctime(dt_sys) dt_sys = dt_sys.split(' ') print("Hora do Sys: ", dt_sys[3])

# CALCULATE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN DATES calc = int(dt_log[3] - dt_sys[3])
```

Código que pega a data do arquivo e do sistema:

```
    # LOG DATE AND SYSTEM DATE
## LOG
dt_log = os.stat(log[0])
dt_log = time.ctime(dt_log.st_ctime)
#dt_log = dt_log.split(' ')
print("Hora da Log: ", dt_log)

## SYSTEM
dt_sys = time.time()
dt_sys = time.ctime(dt_sys)
#dt_sys = dt_sys.split(' ')
print("Hora do Sys: ",dt_sys)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possivel fazer isso com a biblioteca datetime e a função strptime, que transforma uma string em uma data de acordo com um formato.

```
from datetime import datetime

def diferenca_dias(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days * 24)
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
>>> d1 = '20/07/2018 10:05:55'
>>> d2 = '25/07/2018 11:10:02'
>>> print(diferenca_dias(d1, d2))
120
```

Fontes:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419564/difference-between-two-dates-in-python

Edit:
Esses "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" podem ser vistos aqui:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

A função diferenca_dias retorna um timedelta. Para comparar se o returno eh maior ou menor que um numero de dias, podemos comparar: if retorno_da_funcao > timedelta(dias, segundos). Para usar o timedelta() devemos importá-lo (from datetime import timedelta).

Comment: cara obrigado pela ajuda mas encontrei um novo problema.... O retorno que eu tenho é Mon Jul 23 13:49:32 2018

Eu editei com o cód que pega a data

Comment: Então mude o formato da data para:
datetime.strptime(d1, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")).
Esses %a, %b e outros podem ser vistos aqui:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Cara rodou! porém ele só me traz o tempo em dias né? E se quiser colocar por horas (por exemplo o arquivo foi criado às 16:00 e eu puxo o relatorio aqui às 17:30) não me importo muito com minutos mas sim com as horas, tem como ?

Comment: Sim. É só mudar o return para: return abs(d2 - d1). Ou então return abs((d2 - d1).seconds) e transformar os segundos em dias e horas .

Comment: Cara desculpa estar enchendo o saco mas é que sou novato em python, to tentando fazer um if co o retorno (que deu 2 days, 02:37:54) porém ele fala que não posso usar o '>' tem algum jeito de burlar isso?

Comment: A função diferenca_dias() retorna um objeto do tipo timedelta. Podemos comparar dois timedeltas. Podemos escrever: if retorno_da_função > timedelta(dia, segundos). Só não esqueça de importar o timedelta (from datetime import timedelta).

Comment: Cara muito obrigado você literalmente me salvou! Tem algum livro que tu possa indicar pra um aspirar virar um mestre em Python? ou somente o tempo poderá fazer isso?

Comment: Gosto de aprender na prática. Minha recomendação é ler a documentação do Python conforme encontrar problemas para conhecer mais funcionalidades que podem vir a ser uteis e pesquisar na internet.